# Removing/disallowing app does nothing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, api-v2, authentication

I have just deleted/disallowed, the console app and the app I'm currently writing.

For the console the access token I was using before deleting the app carried on working, and when I got a new token, it didn't show the dialog, only opened the blank window before shortly closing it; I was not asked to reject or accept.

For the app I'm developing I don't hold the access token, but it got a new access token without showing the dialog; again I was not asked to accept or reject the app.

I have waited on both apps, still they carry on working, when they should show the Auth dialog.

Refreshing the apps list still shows I have deleted the app.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get prompted when acquiring an access token if you've previously authorized the app and have not explicitly removed it.  That is by design.

I can't reproduce access tokens remaining valid after removing the app, though there is a natural race there.  It's entirely possible that an access token will remain valid for a small period after removing the app as the removal propagates to all the API endpoints.

One possibility is that you were testing while I was looking at [another of your inbox bugs](https://stackapps.com/questions/2827/zero-items-returned-on-inbox-route), I was generated access tokens with under your accounts trying to reproduce the error.  Lining up the timing on those two events is rather difficult though, so it's just a possibility.

Comment: Yes I know the first sentence, I am specifically denying the apps, then using the API. I noticed this about 10-15 minutes before I noticed the other zero items bug, but posted both at the same time so I had time to make sure it wasn't caching or anything. It is still a problem at the moment. Maybe the API releases I am not authorised to access the inbox (hence the zero items), but it is not realising that it should be returning an error, and showing the dialog.

Comment: try this access token (I know I shouldn't post it, but it should become invalid after this is resoled) `rgsA**R6lO5aseFSVy6JBg))` on [the inbox docs page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox)

Comment: @Jonathan. - that access token is associated with [this account](http://stackapps.com/users/9223/jonathan) ; which still has the docs app authorized.

Comment: well then the problem is different, because I created that account to make sure the Facebook login page fitted in the iPhone screen without scrolling (a long time ago, when you could only have 2 open IDs per account). I logged out of that account on this computer before, never used the API with it. Logout says it will log you out on all devices, is that except the API?

Comment: @Jonathan. - bet you're still logged into `stackexchange.com` with those credentials, looks like the se.com user was only created 2 days ago (though the account itself is rather older).  Logging out does nothing to access tokens, for the record, it just doesn't let you create new ones.